# RBL check on DNS way - Proofpoint doesn't work

Tags: spam-prevention, blacklist, dnsbl

If I remember I check [DNS based RBL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNSBL) using a simple command:

`host 12.34.56.170.bl.spamcop.com` (This is a fake ip)

If the DNS returns 127.0.0.2, this host is blacklisted in [Spamcop](http://spamcop.net/bl.shtml).

In [Proofpoint](https://support.proofpoint.com/rbl-lookup.cgi) case, the host to make this check should be: `safe.dnsbl.prs.proofpoint.com`

So it could be:

`host 12.34.56.170.safe.dnsbl.prs.proofpoint.com`

But I don't know why the proofpoint doesn't work in this way.

Answer (score 2):

The difference is that the Proofpoint rbl is a paid service. You can't query it without a license.

If you are curious about a particular ip, you can look it up with this web tool:

https://support.proofpoint.com/rbl-lookup.cgi